# Setting up Eclipse Juno with PyDev and Virtualenv

Tags: eclipse, configuration, pydev, virtualenv

I have managed to set up the python interpreter of my pydev installation to the one in my virtualenv folder following this steps:

1. MyProject -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar
2. Click on "Click here to configure an interpreter not listed"
3. In the section "Python Interpreters" -> new -> Browse -> Select my virtualenv interpreter
4. Select the new interpreter as the default one clicking in the up button with the interpreter selected.

Yei! everything works nice! but... When I use any library installed via pip, my eclipse shows an error mark in the editor, its very annoying because everything works fine!

[image]

I'm thinking of not using PyDev just because of this little detail... Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a little tutorial explaining about it at:

http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2010/04/pydev-and-virtualenv.html

I believe your problem is explained there... (i.e.: after installing something you must restore your interpreter info).

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences/ PyDev/ Interpreters/ Python Interpreter, go to the Libraries tab and add a new folder for the `site-packages` folder where your `virtualenv` packages are installed.